# $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e, a\neq0$ is a function such that $x=1,x=2$ and $x=3$ are normals to the curve. $f(2)$ is always greater than $f(0)$...

Tags: functions

> $f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e, a\neq0$ is a function such that
> $x=1,x=2$ and $x=3$ are normals to the curve. $f(2)$ is always greater than
> $f(0)$. Prove that $f(x)$ has two local maxima

$x=1,2,3$ are points of local maxima or minima. $f'(x)=4ax^3+3bx^2+2cx+d$, upon solving $b=-8a,c=22a,d=-24a$

$f''(x)=12ax^2+6bx+2c$. The question seems incorrect since $f''(x)$ is positive at $x=1,3$, thus it should have two minima and only one maxima.

Comment: Try a function of the form $a(x-2)^4+b(x-2)^2+c$. Why would you expect this to work (think of the symmetry of the specified normals)?

Comment: It seems that you have not used the condition "$f(2)$ is always greater than $f(0)$".

Comment: @mathlove yes I just got it, it's not necessary that $a>0$